# Visual studio 2010 automatically switched to C++/CLI compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, c++-cli

I've been working to a C++/CLI project in the last few months.

Now I'm back to C++ but seems that VS 2010 has set to use C++/CLI compiler even for standard C++ projects.

I just created a new C++ empty project but when I compile the code, it seems using C++/CLI compiler.
Intellisense is disabled as well.

How can I restore the default C++ compiler to my project ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose `Project` -> `Properties` from the menu bar. In the `Project properties` window, under `Configuration Properties` -> `General`, make sure that `Common Language Runtime Support` is set to `No Common Language Runtime Support`.

[image]

Comment: This addresses only a single project; the OP is asking how to change the _default_ project settings.

Comment: well..it seems not to be enough. Intellisense is now enabled but it's still compiling using ClCompile

Comment: @Heisenbug : What is CiCompile? Something third-party? VC++ uses the same compiler for native code and managed code, the only difference being the absence or presence of the `/clr` flag.

Comment: @ildjarn: ok..I didn't know that. Then it's right /clr flags is no more there. The problem is that when I create a new library project, and then add a class it still continue to generate C++/CLI classe: "public ref class" and "using namespace System;"

Comment: @Heisenbug Are you creating a new project using `Visual C++` -> `Win32` -> `Win32 Project`? Or are you using `Visual C++` -> `CLR` -> `Class Library` ?

Comment: @Heisenbug : New _CLR_ Class Library project? Any CLR project  template is going to be C++/CLI by default. You want to use the Win32 project templates. It sounds to me like things are Working As Intended.

Comment: If you use the CLR Class Library, it's going to create a project that uses Managed C++ aka C++/CLI. If you want a plain old C++ project, you need to use Win32 Project. After you choose Win32 project, you get a wizard, and you can choose `DLL` or `Static Library`

Comment: ok..thanks to all...it was my fault. I was choosing the wrong project type.